# LIBGDX Dialog TextButton

Tags: libgdx, dialog, stage, skin

I created a Skin Dialog in my LIBGDX game and added two TextButtons. I added Listeners to them but they are still not clickable.

i've searched all I can all over the internet and stackoverflow and it looks like I'm doing the right thing but I don't know what exactly went wrong

Here's my code:

```
if (uiController.coinsIsReleased){

        label = new Label("GET FREE COINS?", uiSkin);
        label.setColor(0,0,1,1);
        label.setAlignment(Align.center);

        dialog = new Dialog("", uiSkin);

        ok = new TextButton("YES", uiSkin, "small");
        cancel = new TextButton("CANCEL", uiSkin, "small");


        dialog.getButtonTable().add(ok).width(100);
        dialog.getButtonTable().add(cancel).width(100);
        dialog.getContentTable().add(label);

        ok.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeListener.ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {

                System.out.println("OKOKOK");
            }
        });
        cancel.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
         @Override
            public void changed(ChangeListener.ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {

                    System.out.println("CANCELLED");

            }
        });


        stage.addActor(dialog);

        dialog.show(stage);


    }
```

I added an InputMultiplexer and added the Stage and InputAdapter, then I set it as InputProcessor.

Code Below:

```
    multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
    stage = new Stage();
    uiController = new MenuUIController(game);
    multiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
    multiplexer.addProcessor(uiController);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
```

EDIT:

OK I think I have solved the addListener issue using InputListener instead of ChangeListener:

```
    cancel.addListener(new InputListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                //dialog.cancel();
                //dialog.hide();
                System.out.println("CANCELLED");
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I want to cancel the dialog box and continue other operations but the dialog.cancel() and dialog.hide() are not working

Comment: yes I have done that. I used InputMultiplexer

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: Still doesn't work